# Disable first line of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a program like notepad. I want the first line to be the date and time when the note was made. I get this with:

```
tbEditor.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
```

But is it possible to disable this first line so the user can't delete it afterwords?

Comment: Why not just put the date and time in a separate control?

Answer (score 0):

Use a  or  to display data that doesn't require user intervention. You can use a stack with textblock and then a text box in it to store date and user note respectively. Alternatively, if you want to use a textbox, you can set IsReadOnly property to true OR IsEnabled property to false. But this is not just for the first line, but for the whole textbox. So you would need a separate control to store the Date and Time